Angular 404 Error When Fetching Data from Node.js API
I'm working on an Angular component that loads a list of destinations from a Node.js backend using Express. However, I’m encountering a 404 error when attempting to make the request to the API.
Angular Component: DestinationsComponent:
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.loadDestinations(); // Method to load destinations

}

loadDestinations(): void {

    this.destinationService.getDestinations().subscribe(

        (data) => {

            this.destinations = data; // Assign the retrieved data to the variable

        },

        (error) => {

            console.error('Error loading destinations:', error);

        }

    );
}


It uses a service (DestinationService) to perform HTTP requests.
Upon initializing the component (ngOnInit), it calls the loadDestinations method, which attempts to fetch the list of destinations.
getDestinations(): Observable<any> {

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({

        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}` 

    });

    return this.http.get<any>(this.apiUrl, { headers }).pipe(

        catchError(this.handleError) // Error handling

    );

}


Error:
I receive the following error in the console:
GET http://localhost:3000/api/destinos 404 (Not Found)

I've tried:

Verified that the backend server is running.

Checked the API endpoint and ensured it matches with the URL in the service.

Made sure the token is being sent correctly in the headers.


Why might I be receiving this 404 error and how I could resolve it?
